# how to change image dynamically in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, material-design

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';    
  bttnclick(){    
     var a;
     a=(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('browse1')).value    
     console.log(a);        //contains the name of image
     (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('image2')).value=a;
  }
}
```

i am beginner in this field, i want to change the  image source by changing value in the browse box in angular.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to connect two siblings is using a template variable (like `#input` here:

```
<input #input>
<img src="/my/path/{{input.value}}">
```

Comment: my html is    ..<div id="div1"> First assigment  </div
><input type="file" id=image1 >
<button (click)="bttnclick()">submit</button>
<img src="/home/pratap/Desktop/pratap/New Volume/pratap/Camera/home/{{image1.value}}"  id="image2">

Comment: The template variable is missing `<input id=image1 #image1`

Comment: but still not working ....actually iam working on angular 4.. When i check out the path ,that is taking , "http://localhost:4200/home/pratap/Desktop/pratap/New%20Volume/pratap/Camera/home/img002.jpeg"   this path

Comment: what is the expected path?

Comment: exact loaction is       /home/pratap/Desktop/pratap/New%20Volume/pratap/Camera/home/img002.jpeg

Comment: That means the part from my answer is working but you have an extra space at the end?

Comment: sir... you are not understanding the situation ,see the link carefully ... i am working on local host and the image is in my pc . if i move the image to assets folder of local host .then definetely it will work.. but i want to fetch the data frommy system and visualize on local host .  If you have any article related to angular 4 ,give me link because i am just a beginner

Comment: I don't see how this is related to Angular. If you want to fetch the picture from somewhere else, you need to add that part to your path. Your question was about getting the value from the input into the path. My answer seems to work for that. What you ask for now seems to be an entirely different issue.